# How to write non-encapsulated unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I have an autowired variable

```
@Autowired
private DocumentConfig documentConfig;
```

I want to make tests for the DocumentService with various states of this configuration object. What are my options? What is the best option?

The first idea is this:

```
@Test
public void save_failure() {
    documentConfig.setNameRequired(true);
    /*
    testing code goes here
    */
    documentConfig.setNameRequired(false);
}
```

But I want to be somewhat more sure that the variable is reset after the test to not interfere with the other tests, to make sure only this test gets an error if it's the source of a problem.

My new idea was this:

```
@Before
public void after() { documentConfig.setNameRequired(true); }
@Test
public void save_failure() {
    /*
    testing code goes here
    */
}
@After
public void after() { documentConfig.setNameRequired(false); }
```

However, this doesn't work at all because Before and After execute for the whole file and not this single test. I would prefer not to make a new file just for one test.

I've now settled on a compromise:

```
@Test
public void save_failure() {
    documentConfig.setNameRequired(true);
    /*
    testing code goes here
    */
}
@After
public void after() { documentConfig.setNameRequired(false); }
```

It seems to do everything I want but I have a few questions.
Assuming `nameRequired` starts as false, is this guaranteed not to interfere with the other tests?
Is there any way I can make this more clear? Both for my future self and for others.

Comment: What are you testing? DocumentConfig, or another class which depends on DocumentConfig? If the former, use try/finally. If the latter, mock DocumentConfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An often used approach is to set up a dummy `DocumentConfig` and inject it within the `setUp()` method (annotated with `@Before`) so that the entire context is reset within each test, for example:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.documentConfig = new DocumentConfig();
    this.documentConfig.setNameRequired(false);
    this.service = new DocumentService(this.documentConfig);
}
```

In this case, I've set up a simple object with `nameRequired` being `false`. I could probably delete that statement, because a `boolean` field defaults to `false` anyways.

If you don't use constructor injection, and you don't have a setter for `documentConfig`, you'll have to use reflection to inject the field, for example:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this.service, "documentConfig", this.documentConfig);
```

Within your test you could now write something like this:

```
@Test
public void save_failure() {
    this.documentConfig.setNameRequired(true);
    // TODO: Implement test
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could mock `DocumentConfig`, so that you don't rely on its implementation to test `DocumentService`. I assume that you're calling `isNameRequired()` somewhere in the code of `DocumentService`, so you could mock it like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Use a static import for Mockito.mock()
    this.documentConfig = mock(DocumentConfig.class);
    this.service = new DocumentService(this.documentConfig);
}

@Test
public void save_failure()  {
    // Use a static import for Mockito.when()
    when(this.documentConfig.isNameRequired()).thenReturn(true); 
    // TODO: Implement test
}
```

Since this mocking/injection setup happens quite often, Mockito also has its own runner that allows you to get rid of the `setUp()` method, for example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DocumentServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private DocumentService documentService;
    @Mock
    private DocumentConfig documentConfig;

    @Test
    public void save_failure()  {
        when(this.documentConfig.isNameRequired()).thenReturn(true); 
        // TODO: Implement test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create it before each test. Smth like

```
private DocumentConfig documentConfig;

@Before
public void createConfig() {
    documentConfig = new DocumentConfig(mockedParams);
}
```

Comment: I seem to understand this answer and I like it. But wouldn't @After be better than @Before? After all, the objective is to keep the configuration reset at all times, except for in that particular test.
With a change like this, this is actually very similar to my own ultimate solution.
EDIT: I would then also need to assign the variable in the definition, it seems.

Comment: Nevermind, I don't understand it. This does not seem to connect the `documentConfig` in this file with the autowired `documentConfig` in the DocumentService (the main object of these tests) and other files.

Comment: Additionally: I assume you've meant `new DocumentConfig(mockedParams)`, is that  correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is not yet clear, which testing framework you use. For plain unit tests, make the value injectable by either a setter or constructor injection. Whatever suits your specific situation best.

If there's a lot (more than three ;-) ) of such values to be injected, you may consider introducing a configuration class to inject all those values as a single parameter.